# Does Hezbollah break Lebanese law by attacking Israel?

Tags: war, lebanon

Since the October 7 Hamas attack on Israel, [Hezbollah has launched 670 attacks on Israel](https://www.ynetnews.com/article/rj7fniboa) in support of Hamas. This violates the [UNSC decision 1701](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_Resolution_1701), which calls for a full cessation of hostilities between Israel and Hezbollah. My question is whether it also breaks some *Lebanese* law?

- Is there a Lebanese law that ratifies UNSC decision 1701?
- Is there another Lebanese law violated by these attacks?

Comment: how about *attempted murder*, *destructiojn of property* and *assault*?

Comment: @Trish does this law apply for attacks outside Lebanon?

Comment: typically: yes, it is murder prosecutable by **both** origin and target country.